# How to keep entered form data of page1 after navigating back from page2 in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I want to retain the form data entered in first page when I route to page 2 and navigate back on page1
ex: I have created two components: route1 and route2

**route1.component.html**

```
<p>route1 works!</p>
<form>
    <label>Name: </label>
    <input type="text"  [(ngModel)]="name"/>
    <button><a [routerLink] = "'/route2'">route2</a></button>
</form>
```

**route2.component.html**

```
<p>route2 works!</p>
<button><a [routerLink] = "'/route1'">route1</a></button>
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { Route1Component } from './routePages/route1/route1.component';
import { Route2Component } from './routePages/route2/route2.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    {path:'route1' , component : Route1Component},
    {path:'route2' , component : Route2Component}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

I enter any text in route1 page and click on route 2 button. I am now on route 2 page.
I click on route1 button and get back on route1 page. I see that the value I entered in the textbox is not present.

Please help on how to retain the textbox value?

Comment: You can use LocalStorage() to save value When click on route1 and get value in ngOnit

Answer (score 1):

Components are stateless. To have persistent data, you could store the information in a service. And you could retrieve the value in the component from the service upon initialization.

**shared.service.ts**

```js
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class SharedService {
  public nameSource = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');
  public name$ = this.nameSource.asObservable();
  ...
}
```

**route1.component.ts**

```js
import { SharedService } from './shared.service';

import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';

export class Route1 implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  public name: string;
  private closed$ = new Subject<any>();      // <-- use to close subscriptions

  constructor(private shared: SharedService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.shared.name$.pipe(
      takeUntil(this.closed$)               // <-- close subscription when `closed$` emits
    ).subscribe(name => this.name = name);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.closed$.next();         // <-- close impending subscriptions
  }
}
```

**route1.component.html**

```html
<p>route1 works!</p>
<form>
  <label>Name: </label>
  <input type="text" [ngModel]="name" (ngModelChange)="shared.nameSource.next($event)"/>
  <button><a [routerLink] = "'/route2'">route2</a></button>
</form>
```

Comment: Just a note https://twitter.com/michael_hladky/status/1193641068635590656?lang=en

Comment: @yurzui: I guess it's more of a muscle memory at this point. I've updated the answer. Thanks for the tip :)

Comment: No worries, I also wrote this way:)

Comment: Just wanted to add that if you want components to not be destroyed between navigations, you'll have to implement a custom `RouteReuseStrategy`.